# How to make Rails respond to Ajax request with a new Javascript file?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have an Ajax request that comes in to update part of the webpage. This is the code I have doing that:

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html "my_id", :partial => "my_partial"
end
```

As part of this update, I would like to load in some new JavaScript, that handles the behavior of this newly loaded part of the page.

The JavaScript that I have directly included in the partial works perfectly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('reached');
</script>
```

However, the JavaScript I'm loading with a reference inside the partial is not being loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascripts/myScript.js"></script>
```

What's the proper way to be doing this?

Comment: Why not just preload the JavaScript instead of including it in the partial? That way your content and are code are separate.

Comment: @Intelekshual So my JavaScript is specific to handling the content of that partial, and includes setting up observers for elements of the partial. How would I preload the JavaScript when the elements to be observed don't exist yet, and wouldn't it be unnecessarily heavy to preload all the Javascripts for everything a user might do before they have done anything?

Comment: "Unnecessarily heavy" depends on what the application is doing. See dstarh's answer for how to handle elements that don't exist yet.

Comment: if you insist on loading the script separately then you can use jquery's getScript http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the following and it seems to work, not sure if it will work in your situation and you might have to rewrite the javascript for prototype:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var e = document.createElement('script')
e.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
e.setAttribute("src", 'url_of_js_external');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(e);
</script>
```

Comment: btw i think this can also be handled by jquery using getScript() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: The problem is that rails' javascript helpers use prototypejs. since i don't exactly know the prototype api i wrote the possible solution in plain javascript. I'm a big fan of jquery and do suggest to use this where possible.

Comment: Rails is now pretty js agnostic and prototype can be switched out for jQuery without too much pain

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery's live framework should do what you want.  Whipped up an example here

http://jsfiddle.net/bRxxF/

```
$('.doit').live('click',function(){
   $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

Basically you can use live to watch for new dom elements on the page that match your selector and respond to events on them.  This way your javascript is loaded early but only binds once the ajax happens